# UI buttons and images are cruppted after upgrading project to unity 5 on ios

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

Im facing a problem after upgrading my project  on unity5 on ios platform.

 it's working fine on Android and the editor but on is in real device all sprite images and hi buttons are cruppted. 
Screen shot: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/McxvL.jpg

I need help to fix this issue. 

Thanks alot

Comment: Thanks programmer,I fix it by reset  the image  from the inspector

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Reset the image from the inspector was the solution